# Android two buttons side by side into table row

Tags: android, button, user-interface, tablelayout, tablerow

I have a tablelayout with an image and two buttons. I need to put the two buttons in the same row and the same size. 
Now I could align the butons in the same row but it's shown in diferents size.
The background define the image in the butons but not the size.
I define the properties of image in the code.
The code of tablelayout

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/black" > 
<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imagePreLoad"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
                android:background="@drawable/lunafons"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/black" >

        <Button 
                android:id="@+id/btnload"
                android:background="@drawable/btnback"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnload"
                android:background="@drawable/btnloadwallpaper"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

And the code of background butons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btnload1"
     />

<item android:state_enabled="true"
    android:state_pressed="true"
     android:drawable="@drawable/btnload2"
      />
<item android:state_enabled="true"
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btnload1" />
<item android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btnload1" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnload"
        android:background="@drawable/btnback"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnload"
        android:background="@drawable/btnloadwallpaper"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
        />
```

because you're making the width math_parent while it should be 0dp because you are use weight.

Answer (score 1):

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ButtonsTable"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
      <Button 
                android:id="@+id/btnload"
                android:background="@drawable/btnback"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnload"
                android:background="@drawable/btnloadwallpaper"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but isn't valid for my case because The code that I use for modify the properties of tablelayout, make that the buttons show one over another.