# Specific Button Layout

Tags: android, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I would like to have this specific design:

[image]

The texts "A", "B" and "C" are centered.

I offer 200 points if you will propose the solution in xml. It must be made out of 3 buttons. I DON'T need the logic in java. This I can make myself, but I NEED the xml drawables and layout.

**EDIT**

Take into account backward compatibility and android 5 please.

Comment: I believe you are looking to put buttons side by side in a table, similar to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429748/android-two-buttons-side-by-side-into-table-row

Comment: you can use segmented radio button.

Comment: @Shadow: I think there ain't no such a thing in Android SDK. Post a link pls.

Comment: https://github.com/hoang8f/android-segmented-control here it is..check it. @zatziky

Comment: @Shadow: indeed, a nice library but I am not willing to undergo a risk having a lib that get's deprecated over time (which happens often in Android environment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, I misread your question. To me, it seemed like you needed a layout as shown in the picture you posted. But, after looking at the `android-segmented-control` library, its clear that you're looking for a control that allows switching between `A`, `B`, `C`... etc. The library is using `RadioGroup` which is indeed the best option.

I noticed that the library makes use of negative margins which I've read causes problems on some devices. Support for API 21 is also missing.

How xml approach will work: `RadioGroup` is built upon `LinearLayout`. A little known feature (probably because its not suitable most of the time) of `LinearLayout` is its `divider` attribute. If `android:showDividers="..."` is used, a `LinearLayout` will show dividers along with its children. Where these dividers are shown depends on the value given to `showDivider=".."`. Three values are possible: `middle`, `beginning` & `end`. We'll use `middle` to show dividers between `A` & `B`, and `B` & `C`.

For the wired frame, we don't need several drawables (at least, not right now). We can do with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:color="@color/stroke_color" android:width="@dimen/stroke_width"/>
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/corner_radius"/>
</shape>
```

The drawable above will be set as **RadioGroup's background**. And `showDividers` will take care of the vertical divisions between `A`, `B` & `C`. So, our layout looks the same as your posted picture now. Well, with `showDividers`, we also need to provide a `divider` drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/stroke_color"/>
    <size android:width="@dimen/stroke_width"/>
</shape>
```

Now, we need to take care of active states for the `RadioButtons`. Given the rounded corners, we'll need to code 3 different drawables: one for the first child, one for the middle, one for the last. This approach is scalable - first and last drawable remain the same while every child between first & last gets the middle drawable. I've created several gists that you can add to your project:

**API < 21 - place these in `res/drawable`**:

[RadioGroup background](https://gist.github.com/vikramkakkar/b1a24ab1a41e65bccb37)

[RadioGroup divider](https://gist.github.com/vikramkakkar/4269faa0f9ca25ffcc2d)

[RadioButton background for first child](https://gist.github.com/vikramkakkar/e6c477dcfa154eb11c66)

[RadioButton background for middle child](https://gist.github.com/vikramkakkar/eb1bcaed0ab9b40cfecd)

[RadioButton background for last child](https://gist.github.com/vikramkakkar/cc448b8f79a9f31a950d)

**API >= 21 - place these in `res/drawable-v21`**:

[RadioButton background for first child](https://gist.github.com/vikramkakkar/4a4b6987af58ae94112a)

[RadioButton background for middle child](https://gist.github.com/vikramkakkar/49a9d159585a2ea72bda)

[RadioButton background for last child](https://gist.github.com/vikramkakkar/a248f0706916a9a37f07)

**Resources** - contains defined colors, dimensions, and styles - you can either place this file in `res/values` or copy-paste each resource type to its respective file:

[Resources](https://gist.github.com/vikramkakkar/3fea4675752ccb238417)

Finally, here's a sample xml layout that shows how the defined styles make this happen:

[Sample](https://gist.github.com/vikramkakkar/dcb157a2b70af229517d)

In action on API level < 21:

[pre_lollipop.mp4](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9JtTrzjhyi8MUZhZEFHZklkX2c/view?usp=sharing)

In action on API 21:

[lollipop.mp4](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9JtTrzjhyi8YUl3bU5GYkR5OXM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Oh sh it. Now I can start only a bounty of 200. Any Idea how I could give 100? Answer something duplicated on any of my questions and I will give it to you there.

Comment: @zatziky :)) Hey, you don't have to do that. I answered because I thought this was an interesting question. Don't worry about the points. By the way, was my answer useful?

Comment: Yop, it is useful. ;) Accepted!

Answer (score 1):

you need two different shapes, one we rounded corner on the left

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
 <solid android:color="@color/your_color"/>
    <corners
     android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
     android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
  android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
  android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

and one with rounded corner on the right

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
 <solid android:color="@color/your_color"/>
    <corners
     android:topRightRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius
  android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
  android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

as background for the buttons. You can arrange the three buttons on an horizontal `LinearLayout`. To give the three the same width, put `layout_width="0dp"` and `layout_weight="1"`.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I will try it when I have time this weekend. If I will have to combine your solution with someone's else I will split the points.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create three xml drawables

shape_left.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"/>

    <stroke
        android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:width="1dp"/>

    <solid
        android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>

</shape>
```

shape_middle.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke
        android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:width="1dp"/>

    <solid
        android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>

</shape>
```

shape_right.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>

    <stroke
        android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:width="1dp"/>

    <solid
        android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>

</shape>
```

In layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/drawable_left"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_middle"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_right"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Be careful though for buttons in Android 5.0, it may give some issues. But you can put this as background for any view.

I tested it on Android 5.0 and it works. Added transparent color (can be any color) to support older versions. For versions below Android 4.0 you need to create a folder drawable-v14 and put these shapes in there. In the normal drawable folder you should put the same shapes but instead of bottomLeftRadius you should do bottomRightRadius. The same goes for shape_right. This is because of a bug which turns the bottom corners the wrong way.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I will try it when I have time this weekend. If I will have to combine your solution with someone's else I will split the points.

Comment: @zatziky I tested it on Android 5.0 and some earlier phones. I changed my answer to support backwards compatibility

Comment: How to interfere in each shape_*.xml the background color change on active?

Comment: If you want active stages you can better change this to a radiobutton implementation: https://github.com/hoang8f/android-segmented-control if you don't want this library search for uisegmentedcontrol android

Comment: I am going to reward you the bounty. But it's possible tomorrow. Don't worry! ;)

Comment: @zatziky Will this not give you `2dp` sides for the middle button and `1dp` for the leftmost & rightmost sides?

Comment: @Vikram Dunno bro, I fell back to github.com/hoang8f/android-segmented-control. It doesn't do exactly what I wanted but at least seems to be uptodate.

Comment: @zatziky I'll come up with something similar and post an answer. Using a library for this seems like an overkill.

Comment: @Vikram the thing the library does would be the same as what I did once, just override the radiobutton with this as background and changeable colors.

Comment: @Vikram The library is very minimalistic. Check the sources. It's exactly what you would for yourself + one more direction (either Horizontal or Vertical)

Comment: @zatziky My answer will be an extension of Kevin's solution. So, the points should go to him.

Comment: @Vikram If you have a usable answer we should divide the points, but I'm just not sure what you are going to do :P So I'm curious

Comment: Yeah, I promised 200 points. 100 each provided Vikram will finish the job.